# jQuery: $.when().done() doesn't wait / never fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

This has been asked quite a bit on SO, but I couldn't find a resolution to this exact issue.

I'm hoping to synchronously load two functions before calling another function and believe jQuery's `$.when().done()` should work, but I can't figure it out.

Here's some simplified code, and jsFiddle below (in this version, `wrapItUp()` fires immediately):

**HTML:**

```
<span>-</span>
<a>-</a>
```

**javascript (jQuery):**

```
var num = 0;

function funk1() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        num++;
        $("a").text(num);
    }, 750);
};

function funk2() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        num ++;
        $("a").text(num);
    }, 1500);
};

function wrapItUp() {
    $("span").text(num);
};

$.when(funk1(), funk2()).then(function() {
    wrapItUp()
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8pLg3jcm/29/

I've also tried including the following in the `funk()` functions (in this version, `wrapItUp()` never fires at all):

```
var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
...code...
return dfd.promise();
```

Comment: For the love of god, please don't down-vote a well-constructed question unless you're going to leave a helpful comment.

Comment: `$.when` doesn't wait on `undefined`, it just silently moves on. (Neither of your functions return a promise)

Comment: `$.when` takes promises, whereas `funk1` and `funk2` aren't. doing `jQuery.Deferred().promise()` does return one but it's never resolved.

Comment: Right, and as stated, I've tried `var dfd = jQuery.Deferred()` + code + `return dfd.promise()` to each of the functions and the problem there is that then `wrapItUp()` never fires at all.

Comment: @vlaz - can you elaborate on the resolution part of your comment?

Comment: A promise is something that will "be done" in the future. The term is "resolve" as in, "resolve a promise". To do that, you need to call `dfd.resolve()` to signal that the promise is not a potential point in the future any more but it's finished and `done`, `fail`, `complete`, etc stored callbacks will be fired as appropriate.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/csy5wtnd/1/ small dummy example of a deferred with funk1.

Comment: @vlaz & @Taplar - Thank you both!  Taplar, your example did the trick.  I was returning a resolution outside of the `setTimeout()`